# Angularjs $compile input html or element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am reading through the book "Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS" and have come across the following code on page 220:

```
var element = $compile('<button size="large"></button>')($rootScope)
```

However, according to the documentation located at: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler, the $compile function expects an angular.element (wrapped html) input.

Are pure html as well as an angular element both valid inputs to the $compile function (or is one of these documents incorrect)?

Comment: It seems that either are allowed: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile . But maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### When in doubt - [go to the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js).

That's always the best option

```
  if (!($compileNodes instanceof jqLite)) {
    // jquery always rewraps, whereas we need to preserve the original selector so that we can
    // modify it.
    $compileNodes = jqLite($compileNodes);
  }
```

So if it's passed anything but a jqLite element - it wraps it in a jqLite element.

This allows passing content, a jqLite element, or a normal DOM element.

### If you don't find what you're looking for in the source [go to the tests](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/compileSpec.js).

Here you can see it [`$compile`ing HTML text](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/compileSpec.js#L88) in line 88:

```
 element = $compile('<div></div>')($rootScope);
```

Here you can see it [`$compile`ing a jqLite element](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/compileSpec.js#L210)

```
element = jqLite('<div>{{1+2}}</div>');
$compile(element)($rootScope);
```

### If you don't find that in the spec [go to docs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L804).

Huh? That's not the docs! That's the source, you tricked me!

In my experience Angular is *much* better documented in the source code than in the online docs. The documentation is more up to date and all the types and usages are present. It's a lot simpler there:

> - @param {string|DOMElement} element Element or HTML string to compile into a template function.

Although in this case [docs.angularjs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) also does a decent job, it's just longer to navigate.

### Still not there - you can check out [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts).

That's a bunch of type definitions for TypeScript. It's useful since it tells you well - the types :)

```
 interface ICompileService {
        (element: string, transclude?: ITemplateLinkingFunction, maxPriority?: number): ITemplateLinkingFunction;
        (element: Element, transclude?: ITemplateLinkingFunction, maxPriority?: number): ITemplateLinkingFunction;
        (element: JQuery, transclude?: ITemplateLinkingFunction, maxPriority?: number): ITemplateLinkingFunction;
    }
```

As you can see - these are the three options like we found elsewhere. A string, an Element or a JQuery (lite usually) instance.